Typo question concerning a definition for direct limit of the directed system of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then, the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2: The direct sum of the family of the subgroup is defined as
$$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i=\{f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i\}$$
with the restricted operation.
Definition 3:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 4:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 5:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,
if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their iimages in $G_k$.
Questions:
I have a question about possible typo for notations and clarifications about definition 5 which also the notations refers from the four other definitions previous to it.   I will break it up into several posts, since there are more than one or two questions.
In Definition 5 1. where it says "1. if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij},$", should the $i<j$ be $i\preceq j$ instead?  I am assuming that regardless if it is either $<$ or $\preceq$, both are consider as partial ordering of the $i,j$-s
Thank you in advance
